# A home assignment. C language

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Help would be much appreciated.

"Receive a number and reorder it from the largest to the smallest.
Input: 13252
Output: 53221
Cant use arrays...
Only while, for, if/else  ...

any idea? i'm clueless.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Count the number of digits $d$ in the input number. Have a loop go from 1 to $d$. On each iteration, find the largest digit of the input number, and output that number. Anyway, this is offtopic here, and better suited for [SO]. (You should still state what you tried, and where the problem is exactly).

Comment: The problem lays in whether should i use an "int" for the input or a "char". Because i don't know any method of counting the input except for using "getchar" and i also find it problematic to compare the iterations to its previous values with my "limited resources".

Comment: Hint: for counting digits, think of repeated division of the input number by some number.

Comment: Thanks! got this part. How can i "scan" the digits of the integer in order to find the greatest one if you please...

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult if you already know how to count digits. Instead of counting digits, how about you do something else during the iterations? You probably still do repeated division, but what else should you do? Wouldn't it be enough if you just kept track of the largest digits seen so far?

Comment: I think there is an ontopic question in there; I guess the "C" part put us off. If you edit the question to a) be language independent and b) illustrate some effort on your part, we might reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my word! Coding that did take a while. The logic however, is quite simple. Recall the number system.

- First, determine the length of the number entered by the user. You can do so by dividing the number repeatedly by 10 until the quotient becomes zero.
- Then, the maximum value of a digit in decimal number system is 9. So compare each digit in the number with 9. The modulo division operation comes handy in here. See if there's a match. If there's no match go to the next smaller digit, 8 and continue this until you get to zero.
- Multiply the first match found using this procedure with 10^(length-1) *i.e. you are making it your most significant digit (number systems)*
- Reduce the length *length--*
- Continue this procedure until length becomes zero
- A little tip for efficiency, note down the matched digit each time and make that the slab for comparing the remaining digits in the number i.e. if you found out 5 is the first match, and thus the greatest digit found in your number, there's no point starting your comparisons from 9 again for the next digit. Start at 5. Don't be overly smart and start at 4 though. Remember there can be multiple 5's in a number.

I wrote a working piece of code for this. So this algorithm works. Hope that helps. Ways to improvise the performance are appreciated. However, don't suggest the usage of arrays or strings as they are forbidden in the question.